# Algorithm to find is one number divisible by another if they are both large strings?

Tags: algorithm, division

I want to build a function with two arguments. Each argument is a number, but it is a string, not int. Function should return if first argument is divisible by second argument. For example, if we take f("120", "10") it returns True. My problem is that I cannot say int("120") although I am using Python. This int slows down everything if the numbers are really large. How to check divisibility if both numbers are large strings?

Comment: The best way (and probably the fastest way in python) is to convert the strings to int using `int`. What are you doing such that this "slows everything down" too much?

Comment: @PaulHankin I am trying to improve this https://www.spoj.com/problems/INTEST/ in Python. I have 1.29 seconds in speed which is quite slow if we compare to C.

Comment: Please post your code. Note that in the question, the numbers are small (at most 10 digits), not large.